# YouTrack developer permissions working for one user but not for another

Tags: youtrack

YouTrack has a built in role called "Developer" which is assigned to two users. That role allows users to edit issues and change state.
However one of the users is not able to perform these operations although the permissions granted are exactly the same.

We tried the following options:

matching all groups, roles, permissions for both users

clearing browser cache

logging out and logging in

logging in to another machine

restarting YouTrack

But none worked.

Is there a known issue with permissions?

This is YouTrack 7 standalone.

EDIT : Saw a similar issue reported here https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203931930-Developer-Role-Permissions

Comment: Could you please check that the role Developer is granted to the user within relevant projects?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your permission management is out of sync. Please go to Hub Integration page and click on 'Sync' button. This operation will sync internal YouTrack accounts and permissions with Hub accounts and permission (where you are actually setting them up).

Comment: Where exactly is this sync button? There are many pages to navigate in Hub.

Comment: @alok Please find "Hub Integration" link under shell (Administration) icon. The button is located in "Current Hub Export Status" section.